# How to change magento's cms content wrapper

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7. i have tried to change wrapper of cms content but still i cannot get how i can change wrapper of cms_page.

```
<block type="page/html_wrapper" name="cms.wrapper" translate="label">
    <label>CMS Content Wrapper</label>
    <action method="setElementClass"><value>std</value></action>
    <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
</block>
```

and html output is

```
<div class="std">
    CMS Page content
</div>
```

but i want to output like this

```
<section class="std">
    CMS Page Content
</section>
```

Please give me any solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try following code for change div to section

```
<block type="page/html_wrapper" name="cms.wrapper" translate="label">
    <label>CMS Content Wrapper</label>
    <action method="setElementClass"><value>std</value></action>
    <action method="setAttribute"><param1>html_tag_name</param1><param2>section</param2></action>
    <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
</block>
```

this will change div to section because html_wrapper class get tag name from a function `getElementTagName` in `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract\Wrapper.php`

```
/**
 * Wrapper element tag name getter
 * @return string
 */
public function getElementTagName()
{
    $tagName = $this->_getData('html_tag_name');
    return $tagName ? $tagName : 'div';
}
```

so by calling setAttribute we change/set value of `html_tag_name`

Comment: I am getting same html output

Comment: its not possible because have implement this method

Comment: then what problem ?? you think

Comment: what you version of magento using CE or Enterprice

Comment: i am using magento **CE** version

Comment: oohhh m sorry i think i have missed this m checking it